# STL map insertion copy constructor

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have objects of type MyClass stored as pairs `<std::string, MyClass>` in an STL Map. The std::string is a unique name for each MyClass object. I want every MyClass object to be instantiated only ONCE per name and thus destroyed only once at the end in my application. So I try to avoid invocation of copy constructors or default constructors, as they might invoke destruction. A MyClass object refers to some kind of ressource that shall be allocated/freed only once. I tried to use this code to create instances of MyClass, put them in my map and give a pointer to the just created instance back.

```
MyClass* FooClass::GetItem(std::string name)
{
    MyClass* item = GetItemExists(name);

    if (item == NULL)
    {
        item = &(*((this->myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, MyClass>
                                      (name, MyClass(name)))).first)).second;       
    }

    return item;
}
```

Creation and insertion works this way. But the destructor of Class MyClass is called 3! times. Even the `return item;` statement invokes the destructor, as this is a pointer?! I thought this is impossible and must be forced by `delete item`?!

I thought an alternative is to store pointers MyClass* instead of objects in the map. Or is there a better alternative? I did not use `myMap[name] = MyClass(name);` to avoid copy/destruction, but I think insert doesnt make it better.

Comment: Sounds like a good use for `shared_ptr<MyClass>`. Put that in your map instead of `MyClass`. A shared pointer will not copy your MyClass objects and will destruct each one when no longer in use.

Comment: You might also want to derive `MyClass` from `boost::noncopyable` to enforce protection from being copied.

Comment: Ok thx, shared_ptr and boost::noncopyable are good hints, i will use this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to emplace and piecewise construct the inserted element:

```
item = &(this->myMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                             std::forward_as_tuple(name),
                             std::forward_as_tuple(name)).first->second);
```

Comment: Are you sure the `second` part is right? Doesn't emplace return a `std::pair<iterator, bool>`?

Comment: @bamboon oops yeah, forgot the `.first->second` thing, thanks.

Comment: Never saw this before, i will try it, thx. Can you explain why the insert statement invokes constructor/destructor such often and why it is even invoked at return item, although it is a pointer here?

Comment: @MichiMichbeck from what I can tell there should be 2 temporary `MyClass` objects; the innermost temporary and the one within the temporary `pair`.  The invocation at the `return` statement does not correspond to the lifetime of a temporary or local so must be an artefact of your compiler and/or debugger.